# what to use instead of glColor3f?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

It seems as though what i was used to in the stable build of lwjgl has changed. (i updated to nightly) the code that does all the rendering is exactly the same, but at the line

```
 GL11.glColor3f(this.color[0], this.color[1], this.color[2]);
```

eclipse gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This function is not available.
at org.lwjgl.system.Checks.checkFunctionAddress(Checks.java:66)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glColor3f(GL11.java:1923)
```

Searching through google hasn't helped much. i get things on shaders (which is overpowered since i just want a solid colour) and some tutorials using the same line as me.

Eclipse and the docs tell me its depreciated, so do i have to use shaders now?

Comment: You have to use shaders, yes... but more importantly as it pertains to this error, you have to use vertex buffer objects. Immediate mode is gone from core profiles.

Comment: whats the benefit of this? seems like a lot of work just for a solid colour

Comment: @Thedudxo: The benefit, well, reason is, that in modern GPUs there is no reason to have specialized vertex attributes. What makes "colour" color in an environment, where you have to explicitly write a shader, that assigns that colour to the fragment. You could, if you wanted to, use the values coming in from a "glColor" attribute for modifying the vertex position. Hence, since there's no longer special meaning attributed to the vertex inputs it makes no sense to give them special names. Instead you get generic vertex attributes.

Comment: will this hinder the programs ability to run on older hardware?

Comment: If you use graphic card older than 10 years you may have a problem